# Miller-Rabin Primality Test in python: Why I keep getting decimal.Overflow: [<class 'decimal.Overflow'>]?

Tags: python, primality-test

I was trying to do the [Miller-Rabin Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) in python. I've written the code like below based on [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_test) on Wikipedia:

```
from math import *
from numpy import *

def Miller_Rabin(n, k):    #Miller-Rabin Primality Test
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    s = n - 1
    d = 0
    r = 0

    while True:
        if s % 2 == 0:
            r += 1
            s /= 2

        else:
            d = s
            break

    for i in range(k):

        a = random.randint(2, n-1)
        t = a**d
        x = t % n

        if x == 1 or x == n-1:
            continue

        for j in range(r-1):
            x = x**2 % n

            if x == n-1:
                continue

        return False
    return True
```

But when I run the code and enter a prime number like 5336101, I got the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\kienp\Documents\Math Projects\Primality Test\primality_test.py", line 46, in Miller_Rabin
    t = a**d
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

So I decide to use the Decimal module, modified a few lines of code:

- **Adding part:**

```
from decimal import Decimal  #Adding
from decimal import Context  #Adding
```

- **Modifying part:**

```
    for i in range(k):

        a = random.randint(2, n-1)
        t = Decimal(Decimal(a)**Decimal(d))
        x = Decimal(t) % n
```

But then I got another error:

```
File "C:\Users\kienp\Documents\Math Projects\Primality Test\primality_test.py", line 46, in Miller_Rabin
    t = Decimal(Decimal(a)**Decimal(d))
decimal.Overflow: [<class 'decimal.Overflow'>]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you are using Python 3 where `x / y` always returns a `float` even if the operand types are both `int`. `float` is limited in what it can represent to an overflow error can occur. In order to perform integer division you can use `x // y`. Specifically in your code the line `s /= 2` should be changed to `s //= 2`.